# Get value of from data object

Tags: java

How to get value of single element from the data object that contains a row of a table in java?

```
Integer str = 100;
Criteria cr = new Criteria(new Column("TableName","COLUMN_NAME"),str,QueryConstants.EQUAL);
DataObject dobj = per.get("TableName",cr);
```

Here, `dobj` contains a single row from which I have to get value of a single column.

Comment: Please specify what library you're using.

Comment: If you are using the library I think you are using, I guess it's pretty straightforward. Check this: http://people.apache.org/~svkrish/tuscanySite/apidocs/sdo/commonj/sdo/DataObject.html